# Very high contrast in indoor model

Tags: light, lighting

I'm new to blender and am trying to create an indoor model. I've emulated fluorescent lighting with some point lights placed inside a glass cylinder. For some reason the contrast in my model is very high. This is a demonstration of the effect with a single point light. I have added a noise texture to the room.
[image]

I think the reason is that light isn't bouncing off the walls and other surfaces nicely. So would this problem be resolved once I add correct textures to the surfaces or do I need to tweak some setting in blender?

In the former case, how things do I need to keep in mind while adding the textures?

Comment: Can't really give a full answer for this, but I would recommend looking up a tutorial for Three-point lighting in blender. The render you're showing is pretty much what I'd expect from a single light in a completely dark room. You'll need fill and rim lighting to make the scene look better.

Answer (score 1):

The contrast primarily depends on the light in the scene. If it's one strong small light source, there will be more contrast. If there was some light maybe coming from the windows, or other light sources, the lighting would be more uniform and there would be less contrast. Obviously to have ambient lighting you need the light to be able to bounce around the scene, so render settings should allow calculating enough of light bounces:

[image]

It does not have to be 128 bounces for everything, just make sure there are a few where it makes sense.

Comment: I can't find the `light paths` group in camera settings. In my install, `Freestyle` is the last group. What build of blender are you using?

Comment: I wrongly assumed Cycles render engine since it was not specified. If you are using EEVEE, you will have to use irradiance volumes for global illumination.